# Installing meme package in R

Tags: r

There's a new package called `meme` in R. I tried installing it using the following code:

```
install.packages("meme")
```

However, each time I get an error in the following format:

```
also installing the dependency ‘gridGraphics’

installing the source packages ‘gridGraphics’, ‘meme’

trying URL 'http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/src/contrib/gridGraphics_0.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 64486 bytes (62 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 62 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/src/contrib/meme_0.0.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 13479 bytes (13 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 13 KB

* installing *source* package ‘gridGraphics’ ...
** package ‘gridGraphics’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in system("convert --version", intern = TRUE, ignore.stderr = TRUE) : 
  error in running command
Error : unable to load R code in package ‘gridGraphics’
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘gridGraphics’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/gridGraphics’
ERROR: dependency ‘gridGraphics’ is not available for package ‘meme’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/meme’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/47/71_55p097y94jptwk6t75f8w0000gn/T/Rtmpulde6u/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("meme") :
  installation of package ‘gridGraphics’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("meme") :
  installation of package ‘meme’ had non-zero exit status
```

It seems R is having trouble installing a dependency package -`gridGraphics`. I tried installing `gridGraphics` using `install.packages("gridGraphics")` but I got the following error:

```
installing the source package ‘gridGraphics’

trying URL 'http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/src/contrib/gridGraphics_0.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 64486 bytes (62 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 62 KB

* installing *source* package ‘gridGraphics’ ...
** package ‘gridGraphics’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in system("convert --version", intern = TRUE, ignore.stderr = TRUE) : 
  error in running command
Error : unable to load R code in package ‘gridGraphics’
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘gridGraphics’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/gridGraphics’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/47/71_55p097y94jptwk6t75f8w0000gn/T/Rtmpulde6u/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("gridGraphics") :
  installation of package ‘gridGraphics’ had non-zero exit status
```

Any ideas? Here's a link to a page discussing the package's features: https://www.r-bloggers.com/creat-meme-in-r/

Comment: From the CRAN page for `gridGraphics`, that package requires that you have `ImageMagick` installed and available on your machine. The `convert` program should be on your system path it looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gridGraphics needs [ImageMagick](https://github.com/cran/gridGraphics/blob/master/DESCRIPTION#L14). I will remove this dependency in future release. As a tiny package, it is not a good idea to have system dependency.